# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable at line results = data['responseData']['results']

Tags: python

When I run the code, it turned out to be like this:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I am a Python beginner. I just picked a sample project from a site for Python beginner: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/google-command-line-script/
I am using Pycharm Community Edition. After refering to online web search help, I edited some lines of code to run through but finally I got stuck by this error.
Thank for your help.

```py
import json
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
import urllib.request

url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"

query = raw_input("What do you want to search for ? >> ")

query = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': query})

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url + query).read()

data = json.loads(response)

results = data['responseData']['results']

for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']
    print(title + '; ' + url)
```

Comment: which version of python do you use? the urllib module changed significantly between Python 2 and 3. This might be the cause of your error

Comment: Do you run the script in the python console? I think the script was made to run from command line

Comment: `The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)', 'responseStatus': 403}`

Comment: I think I should start with something easier than this. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's expected that website will send you something containing responseData and it should contain results, but for some reason (error?) they sent you different data. **Always** check what you've got before using.

Here's how to check whether you recieved what's expected:

```
if 'responseData' in data:
      if 'results' in data['responseData']:
              #-- do stuff 
      else:
              print('Error: no results. Data was:' + data)
else:
      print('Error: no responses. Data was:' + data)
```

Additionally you can try using pprint command to print structure of data, to see what you've got:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

This will help you in all steps to see what actual response you got, what data is, etc.